# How to make a button go on with the current scene and go then to another one?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

Sorry for my bad english! I will try to be as clear and detailed as possible.

I have some scenes on a flash file. On every scene there will be some buttons to go to each scene.

On the main scene (the "intro") there are some little animations and stuff at the beginning. Then the whole thing stops and there's some other animations (as an "outro"), before it goes to another scene.

The thing I can't figure how to do, is that if I click on one of those buttons (say "go to scene 2") the main scene resume its playing (in other words, I want it plays the "outro" and *then*, after playing the outro, it goes to scene 2: I linked the buttons to their scenes (with `gotoAndPlay("Scene X", 1);`), but it makes the movie go immediately to that scene...

Any advice about how I can do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to keep track of which scene to go to in a global variable.

Something like this: (untested)

Main timeline first frame:

```
var curScene:String = "defaultSceneLabel";
```

Then, at the end of your outro scene (last frame) do this:

```
gotoAndPlay(_root.curScene,1);
```

Then, on your scene buttons:

```
_root.curScene = "scene to go to";
gotoAndPlay("outro",1);
```

Comment: So clever! I was struggling at this (even it seems so simple). I guess I was too rusty to Flash and AS2 stuff. Thank you so much!